# Firebase getAuth returns null across iframes

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I have also posted this question on the Firebase Google Group, which apparently I should not do in the future: https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/firebase-talk/ma3qADOsN7E

I have multiple iframes on a page, all accessing the same application on the same domain. When I log in my user in one iframe, the change is not detected by getAuth on the other iframes. Even when logged in on one iframe, getAuth returns null on the other iframes until the page is refreshed and the iframes are reloaded. I'm not sure why this is. I presumed that getAuth was reading the localStorage object that has the user authentication information in it, and since my iframes are all from the same domain, why can they not see the authentication information that the first iframe wrote to localStorage?

Comment: Cross-post? https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/ma3qADOsN7E

Comment: Yes, should I remove one of them?

Comment: At the very least indicate that you posted the question in multiple places. But not cross-posting would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue anymore with new firebase SDK versions.